# Django Jinja2 - AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'get_source'

Tags: python, django, jinja2, visualization

I have the following two lines of code. Both are using jinja2 to replace the template variables:

```
subject = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(template.email_subject).render(context)
body = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(template.email_template).render(bodyContext)
```

The first line works just fine, while the second line throws the Error:

```
 AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'get_source'
```

The context dictionary includes all necessary template variables and the jinja2 syntax should be correct as well. Just to be sure, here are the templates as well:

template.email_template:

```
Hallo {{name}},
{%- include invoiceType+'/email_body.tpl' -%}
Viele Grüße
{{emailFooter}}
```

invoiceType/email_body.tpl:

```
im Anhang findest du/findet ihr den Entwurf für die kommende Rechnung
über alle angefallenen Kosten bis zum {{invoiceDate -}}.
```

template.email_subject:

```
Rechnung {{currentYear}}{{invoiceID}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by writing the string into a file and load it from the file.

```
        template_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'invoice\\templates')
        loader = FileSystemLoader(template_dir)
        environment = Environment(loader=loader)
        body = environment.get_template("email.tpl").render(bodyContext)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).